# UPDATE oracle en java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

tengo un problema con un UPDATE en java, este recibe un parametro,  no se ejecuta, mi sintaxis la pondre aca, alomejor hay algo que se me olvida, por lo que he visto en la net, esta bien pero no se que pasa :c

```
public void CollectRv(String Bcode){
      try{
    ConexionOracle conexionOracle = new ConexionOracle();
    conexionOracle.conectar();
    Connection conn = conexionOracle.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE tabla\n" +
                    "set tabla.estado = 1 \n" +
                    "where tabla.task_class_cd = 'CHECK' \n" +
                    "and tabla.estado = 0 \n" +
                    "and num = 3002000 \n" +
                    "and sched= (select sched from tabla where num =3002000 and code= ?");
    ps.setString(1,Bcode.trim());
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
    conn.close();
    conexionOracle.cerrar();
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Consulta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puede `campo` tener valor `0`, `3002000` y `?` a la vez? Has probado tu consulta en un sistema de gestión de base de datos? Notar que `campo` y `tabla.campo` es lo mismo.

Comment: Definitivamente creo que el problema es el que comenta Rosendo  "and tabla.campo= 0 \n" +
                    "and campo= 3002000 \n" . Otra cosa, en verdad tu tabla se llama "tabla" ?

Comment: @Elenasys claro que la tabla no se llama tabla, solo cambie los nombres por tema de seguridad, la solución fue un cambio mínimo, que no lo veía, meti la query en una variable de tipo String y lo ejecute de esta manera y funciono :
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,Bcode.trim());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        conn.close();
        conexionOracle.cerrar();

Comment: @elsa ¿Sin cambiar tus condiciones en el `where`? Entiendo que el query es fictisio pero, realmente era lo que daba a entender.

Comment: @RosendoRopher sin cambiar las condiciones en el where, el o hace referencia a un estado desactivado y el 1 activado, entonces cuando ese usuario lo encontraba desactivado, lo activa, gracias

Comment: @elsa creo que el problema surge porque tienes `WHERE campo = ... AND campo = ...`. Si vas a indicar que son diferentes campos, puedes colocar `WHERE campo1 = ... AND campo2 = ...` o algo similar para que comprendamos que son diferentes campos. Si lo que sucede es que quieres actualizar un campo en una tabla1 a partir de buscar en una tabla2, entonces creo que eso es lo que deberías expresar en la pregunta.

Comment: @elsa te aparece algún error al momento de hacer un debug?

Answer (score 1):

meti la query en una variable de tipo String y lo ejecute de esta manera y funciono :

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
                   ps.setString(1,Bcode.trim());
                   ps.executeUpdate();
                   ps.close(); 
                   conn.close(); 
                   conexionOracle.cerrar();
```

Comment: Francamente, esto no explica cual fue el problema para nada. Mover el string a un variable no deberia causar ninguna diferencia. Debe haber otra explicacion.